# change selected value of drop-down list - two way binding

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown which I would like to change its selected value in some cases.
At the moment, I'm using two-way binding but when changing the value from `ts` file, the value isn't changing. I must been missing something.

The HTML code:

```html
 <form class="teamForm">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-6 right" *ngFor="let player of playersArray; let i=index">
         <label class="col-12 col-md-4 right">
             name: <span class="fa fa-futbol"></span>
             <input [(ngModel)]="player.name"
             class="form-control input-lg"
             name="playerName{{i}}"
             />
         </label>
         <label class="col-12 col-md-2 right">
             rate: <span class="fa fa-futbol"></span>
             <select [(ngModel)]="player.rate" (change)="checkRatingLimit($event.target.value, player)" name="playerRate{{i}}" class="form-control">
              <option [ngValue]="0">Choose</option>  
              <option *ngFor="let rating of ratingList" [ngValue]="rating.value">{{rating.key}}</option>
              </select>
         </label>
       </div> 
      </div>
</form>
```

The `ts` code:

```js
checkRatingLimit(rating: string, player:Player)
{
  
  let ratings : Player[] = this.playersArray.filter(p => p.rate == Number(rating));
  if(ratings.length>this.teams)
  {
    debugger;
    player.rate = 0;
    console.log(this.playersArray)
  }
```

I'm expecting the `select` to be changed when `player.rate = 0` is being executed and then to have the `0` value as the selected value in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you share a [plunker demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/) for the same?

Answer (score 0):

## A solution for reactive form

Simplest SELECT

```
 <form [formGroup]="countryForm">
     <select formControlName="countryControl">
      <option [value]="country" *ngFor="let country of countries">{{country}}
      </option>
     </select>
 </form>
```

And in .ts file

```
countryForm: FormGroup;
countries = ['USA', 'Canada', 'Uk']
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {
 this.countryForm = this.fb.group({
   countryControl: ['Canada']
 });

//to change the value programmatically you need to patch the value
this.countryForm.patchValue({
   countryControl:  ['USA']
});
}
```